# Angular: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'NODE_DEBUG')

Tags: angular

After update to Angular 13 from 10 got error with NODE_DEBUG:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw1w7.png)

I've tried few solutions but nothing resolved this issue.

1. Changed `polyfill.ts` file with code: `(window as any).process = { env: { DEBUG: undefined } };` generate another error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKAzF.png)
2. I've deleted whole folder with `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and this also didn't work.
3. Even if I've been back to Angular 12 problem stays with me.
4. I've tried delete jsonwebtoken dependency which was pointed by another user with similar problem but this also didn't repair anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually update polyfill.ts. After deleting the node_modules folder. What did you do? Run `npm install`?

Comment: Yes `npm install`, but after that, run `ng serve` and then got error in web browser

Comment: Try creating a brand new Angular 13 app and compare the angular.json file with the one you have. It's possible that something might have changed in the new version.

Comment: I've tried this way, but I didn't find anything strange in my project when compare to v13. I even tried back to v10 (app work correctly) and then use Angular Update Guide (`https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=10.0-11.0`) to update to v11 but after verify all points on list get error from my original post

Comment: I resolved problem by deleting library `crypto-random-string`, before that I've updated Angular from 10 to 11, from 11 to 12 and finally from 12 to 13 using Angular Update Guide. I also left `(window as any).process = { env: { DEBUG: undefined } };` in my `polyfill.ts`.I used to test few versions of nodejs but finally running version 14.19.1